# en/decryption using php and Objective-C

Tags: php, encryption, wamp, wampserver, mcrypt

I'm trying to use function that decrypt for me ciphertext
after encrypted using Objective-C

I know that the problem is in padding.

so I found this function form this site.

http://tharindufit.wordpress.com/2011/12/15/aes128-encryption-in-ios-and-decryption-in-php/#comment-470

thanx for the guy posted.

```
function decrypt_password($pass,$key)
{

    $base64encoded_ciphertext = $pass;

    $res_non = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, base64_decode($base64encoded_ciphertext), ‘ecb’);

    $decrypted = $res_non;
    $dec_s2 = strlen($decrypted);

    $padding = ord($decrypted[$dec_s2-1]);
    $decrypted = substr($decrypted, 0, -$padding);

    return  $decrypted;
}
```

The result I found is this:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant ‘ecb’ - assumed '‘ecb’' in C:\wamp\www\enc3.php on line 7

Warning: mcrypt_decrypt() [function.mcrypt-decrypt]: Module initialization failed in C:\wamp\www\enc3.php on line 7
```

Can any one help to make the code work greatly since i need it with same result to use it in decrypt the recived ciphertext from Objective-C?

by the way I use wamp server 2.0 that support mcrypt function.

Answer (score 0):

Fix your keyboard. You wrote a `‘` while you should have used a `'`. I'm sure they look very similar but one of them works and the other one doesn't.

`‘ecb‘` won't work. It's `'ecb'`

Comment: Thanx dude. I use it , The error is gone , but I didn't got any result.

I use this code to test it
$passValue = "Iphone 5";
$keyValue = "0000";

$var = decrypt_password($passValue,$keyValue);

echo $var;